# cairo multiply values with alpha channel included

Tags: cairo

I want to achieve

```
source.rgba * dest.rgba
```

with cairo. Is that possible without writing the loop manually? The multiplication operator still uses alpha-over, which is not the right thing.

One of the operands is a possibly rotated mask, and the other one is a shadow map that is not rotated. Here are the pictures. The mask will be visible if you open it in Gimp, where multiplication does exactly what I want.

[image: White mask] [image: Shadow map] [image: Result]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?